# Javascript post requests cross domain with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Using Javascript I want to make multiple POST requests cross domain. In the first instance, I store the response cookies in a variable, then I resend for a second POST request..

For example, in ruby i'd do something like this:

```
@http = Net::HTTP.new("myhost.com", 80)

// first request
data = "param1=xxxx&param2=yyyy&param3=zzzz"
resp = @http.post("/firstrequestform", data, {'User-Agent'=>'me'})

// second request
@cookie = resp['set-cookie']
headers = { "Cookie" => @cookie, "Referer" => "http://myhost.com/firstrequestform" }
data = "param1=xxxx&param2=yyyy&param3=zzzz"
resp = @http.post("/secondrequestform", data, headers)
```

Is it possible to do this in Javascript given cross domain restrictions. Maybe possible using an iframe, but how would you control the cookies? I'd also like to set custom headers within the iFrame, such as the Referer header.

If it's not possible, does anyone know of a browser plugin that can be used to do this?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Unfortunately in this case its not possible to route any request through a 3rd party server (all the code has to be on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be use your server as a  proxy. Make an AJAX  request to your server, and use your Ruby code shown to make request to other domain and output the response to AJAX request

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the code needs to all run on the client side, cannot run at all through a 3rd party server. This is part of the software requirements. I'll add that to the original post

Comment: could do it with a browser extension if that is allowed in spec

Comment: you would need to create one on a browser specific basis. Not sure if IE supports extensions the way Chrome or Firefox do. Most likely not able to in older versions